# How can I show modal form

Tags: html, css

How can I show modal form?

I don't know why this modal form no show..

I used thymeleaf server template

```
<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#exampleModal">Launch demo modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">...</div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <h2>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Software Contents</a>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    //some code about session
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
                <p>
                <h1 class="page-header">Q&A 게시판</h1>
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    //some code
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Have you done any research on that

Comment: i was research that no have problem this modal, But this html file no working

Comment: To make things easy you should set up fiddle to have the complete picture, this also get quick response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code

```
<html>
<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#exampleModal">Launch demo modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">...</div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <h2>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Software Contents</a>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    //some code about session
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
                <p>
                <h1 class="page-header">Q&A 게시판</h1>
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    //some code
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aha not match bootstrap version.. thank you for your kind :D